# Lost the first letter when reading a file

Tags: c++, file

```
void ReadCourse(ifstream& fin, Course& c) {
    getline(fin, c.courseID, '\n');
    getline(fin, c.courseName, '\n');
    getline(fin, c.lecturerUser, '\n');
    getline(fin, c.lecturerName, '\n');
    getline(fin, c.lecturerDegree, '\n');
    fin >> c.lecturerGender;
    /*fin.ignore();*/
    fin >> c.startDay.year >> c.startDay.month >> c.startDay.day;
    fin >> c.endDay.year >> c.endDay.month >> c.endDay.day;
    fin >> c.Day;
    /*fin.ignore();*/
    fin >> c.hourStart.hour >> c.hourStart.minute;
    fin >> c.hourEnd.hour >> c.hourEnd.minute;
    fin.ignore();
    getline(fin, c.Room, '\n');
}
void ReadFileCourse(Course*& c, int& n) {
    ifstream fin("Course.txt", ios::in);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "Can not open file" << endl;
        return;
    }
    fin >> n;
    c = new Course[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fin.ignore();
        ReadCourse(fin, c[i]);
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

It's error

Hi when I run this Program in file Course.txt have 4 elements

```
4
CS162
Introduction to Programing
dbtien
Dinh Ba Tien
TS
1
2020 04 01
2020 06 01
2
7 30
11 30
I42
CM101
Communications
dnvu
Duong Nguyen Vu
GS
1
2020 04 05
2020 06 03
7
13 30
17 30
I43
CM102
Commun
dnvan
Duong Nguyen Van
GS
1
2020 04 08
2020 06 09
6
13 30
17 30
I43
HK162
To Programing
dtly
Dinh Thi Ly
TS
1
2020 04 01
2020 06 01
4
7 30
11 30
I42
```

But when read it , CourseID will lost first letter when n>0

This's the picture that I used to debug to find the error
Exam [Debug find error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OT7h.png)
When I call this function int main() then I start run debug . I find this error and I took a picture to description error

Why is that? Please Help me

Subject names are assumed

Comment: Mixing `getline()` and formatted stream input (`operator>>`) is in general good for such issues. To fix this, you could read everything with `getline()` and use the formatted input on a `std::istringstream` for the resp. lines where needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
fin.ignore();
ReadCourse(fin, c[i]);
```

`fin.ignore();` ignores a single character -- no surprise here.